# How to leave out figures in appendix from list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, appendices

Nothing seems to work.

I've tried adding * to `\caption`.
I've tried adding `\captionsetup{list=no}` to the preamble before the `\appendix` entry.

I'm using `\usepackage{caption}`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

## Ending the `.lof` file with `\endinput`

A trick is to end the file `.lof` via `\endinput`. Then TeX will not read the lines after `\endinput`, when the file is `\input` in the list of figures:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \if@filesw % \nofiles is not active
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
      \string\@writefile{lof}{\string\endinput}%
    }%
  \fi
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \listoffigures
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{First figure caption}
  \end{figure}
\newpage
\appendix
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure caption not in list of figures}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Then the `.lof` file contains:

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces First figure caption}}{1}
\endinput 
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {2}{\ignorespaces Figure caption not in list of figures}}{2}
```

And only the first entry is shown.

## Disabling `\addtocontents` for `.lof` file in `\appendix`

The following example redefines `\addtocontents` in `\appendix` to do nothing, if the contents is meant to go into the list of figures:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \newcommand*{\SavedAddToContents}{}%
  \let\SavedAddToContents\addtocontents
  \renewcommand*{\addtocontents}[1]{%
    \def\atc@next{\SavedAddToContents{#1}}%
    \edef\atc@handle{#1}%
    \def\atc@lof{lof}%
    \ifx\atc@lof\atc@handle
      \let\atc@next\@gobble
    \fi
    \atc@next
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \listoffigures
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{First figure caption}
  \end{figure}
  \appendix
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure caption not in list of figures}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The `.lof` file contains:

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces First figure caption}}{1}
```

## Option `list=no` of package `caption`

At least with the simple example file, the option setting `list=no` works, if added to `\appendix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \captionsetup{list=no}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \listoffigures
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{First figure caption}
  \end{figure}
  \appendix
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure caption not in list of figures}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

File `.lof` contains only the first figure caption:

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces First figure caption\relax }}{1}
```

## Manual disabling the list entry with package `caption`

Also the manual method by specifying an empty caption title for the list of figures works here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
  \listoffigures
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{First figure caption}
  \end{figure}
  \appendix
  \begin{figure}
    \caption[]{Figure caption not in list of figures}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would put `list=no` from caption at the top of the answer, as it is the most simple and convenient way to achieve the result.

Comment: @Johannes_B The OP says, this does not work for him for some unknown reason. Also the first two versions suppress `\addvspace` commands added by `\chapter`s.

Comment: Ah right, but it also says *I've tried adding \captionsetup{list=no} to the preamble before the \appendix entry.* which is kind of confusing?